# Regular expression to get name using id from html string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to parse html string using a regular expression.

Full html is loaded in a string variable and i know the id of the element. How to get the name of that particular element

in the below example id is `field-options-Real-fc` and the expected result is `f4186d62184e277e2968ece68da25a860`
Can anyone help me with the regular expression to match the name ? 
value property is also unique  and the html format is remains same.

```
   <li class="field-choice field-choice-radio ">
      <input type="checkbox"  data-disable-children="true" data-validation-count="1..6" data-validation-count-message="Must specify within 1 and 6 items." 

name="f4186d62184e277e2968ece68da25a860" 

value="131233102" 

id="field-options-Real-fc" class=""/>
      <label for="field-options-Real-fc">
        <span>Real FC</span>
      </label>
    </li>
```

Comment: You should never use regex for this sort of thing, because it will break if any 1 of 1000 different special cases happen (the `id=""` gets moved before/after the `name=""`, spaces anywhere in the HTML (which is valid), etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use XML parsers like BeautifulSoup (python)

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(your_html_string)
elem = soup.find(id="field-options-Real-fc")
name = elem['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Positive Lookahead to find the id, then use a capturing group (`$1`) to pull the ID itself, terminating the group at the next double quote.

```
(?=id=")id="(.*)"\s
```

## [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aS4tDr/1/)

---

Edit: This still works with your [latest revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49344763/4).

## [DEMO <sup><sub>(Revised for Rev#4)</sub></sup>](https://regex101.com/r/aS4tDr/2)

Answer (score 0):

To cover all (two) possible orders or attrs, use lookahead:

```
/\<(?=(?:[^>]|"[^"]*")*id="field-options-Real-fc")(?:[^>]|"[^"]*")*name="([^"]*)"/
```

`(?:[^>]|"[^"]*")` is needed here to disallow a '>' character unless quoted.

https://regex101.com/r/aS4tDr/3